# Which language for web app with complex UI?

Tags: reactjs, flask, web-applications

## Context

Our project has a Java back-end that accesses a Neo4j database. The back-end is nearly finished. Previously we intended to build a Java desktop client with a JavaFX UI. Now we are considering building a web application instead. I will be building the front-end. My previous experience was mostly using Java. I will have to learn a new language. The thing I'm having some trouble with is determining which one is best suited for this project. Before we begin front-end development we also want to ensure that the web app will be able to handle all features we had planned for the desktop client.

## Requirements

- Connection

  - Send HTTPS requests (not expecting any problems here)
  - Keep a persistent HTTPS connection open to receive server-sent events
- Data

  - Store and handle considerable amounts of information received through server-sent events (potentially millions of events)
- UI

  - Create a beautiful and highly reactive UI
  - Create complex custom components
  - Drag and drop support (also not expecting any problems here)
  - Integrate a view of an external site into the UI
- Platform

  - Platform independence
  - No need for browser plugins

## Candidates

These are some candidates I have identified during my research:

- JavaScript with React
- ASP.NET
- Python with Flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React js for the front end.  Most anything for the backend.  We use Python/Flask for routing and inserting into templates.  But, you will really appreciate React for its "reactive" UI.  It's incredible what it can do. I see no problems with the task list you've given.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I had a feeling React would be a good fit.